# change what ssh remote command will be executed

Tags: ssh, openssh

The command:

```
  ssh user@server 'command1; command2'
```

creates a ssh connection to server under the account user and then interprets *command1; command2* under command *bash -c*, but the command:

```
  ssh user@server 'command1'
```

executes *command1* directly.  I know this through experimentation as there was no info on this that I could find.

My question is, can I specify what interpreter is used or any additional parameters are used on the interpreter?

Thanks,

A

Comment: You might have better luck with this question if you post it on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

The most widely used SSH server is the [OpenSSH ssh server](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd). It always executes commands requested by clients using the user's shell. It invokes the equivalent of this `sh` syntax:

```
$SHELL -c 'the command with its arguments'
```

If you want to invoke an alternate interpreter, you'd have to construct a shell command that does what you want:

```
$ ssh localhost 'exec perl -le "print scalar localtime"'
Mon Nov 27 11:10:33 2017
$
```

You say that running this invokes `command1` directly:

```
ssh user@server 'command1'
```

You may have misinterpreted what was happening. If the remote user's shell is `bash`, then bash optimizes this case and invokes `command1` without creating a subprocess. This is a special behavior of the `bash` shell (and possibly other shells), not OpenSSH. So if you inspected the processes running on the remote server, it might look like OpenSSH had invoked `command1` without using a shell. But that's not what happened.